# How to update specific row in realm using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using latest RealmSwift.I can open the **default.realm**  file using **Realm browser** from the specified path.Please go through the image

[image]

Then I tried to update the specific row using the following code.

```
static func update(_ code: String, _ titleEnabled: Bool) {
        do {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"Code = %@", code)
            let realm = try Realm()
            if let object1 = realm.objects(RealmModel.self).filter(predicate).first {
                realm.beginWrite()
                object1.boardTitleEnabled = titleEnabled
                realm.add(object1, update: true)
                try realm.commitWrite()
            }
        } catch {}
    }
```

When I open the default.realm file then updating does not happen.It always fails the updation. 
The updation successfully happend only when before opening default.realm file using Realm browser.
Please help me.

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need for the `realm.add(object1, update: true)` line, mutating a managed object will be saved to Realm automatically, since it can only be done in a write transaction. Also, what device/simulator are you using? If you are using a 32bit device/simulator, that can easily explain the issue. Also, if you only open Realm browser __after__ you change a value, can you see that the value actually changed?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure that the code within the `if let` predicate is actually being run?